# Echo JSON array specific element

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I'm confused about how I can echo a certain element in my JSON array.

Under time series (1min), I would like to output 1. open. In order to give me the actual value for it.

So far, i'm only able to output the complete array.

Link to JSON file is: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo

Also, i'm using wordpress.

Here is the code i'm using:

```js
$request = wp_remote_get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo');

if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
 return false; // Bail early
}

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );

$data = json_decode($body, true);

echo $body;
```

Comment: How is this related to `javascript` or `jquery` ?

Comment: I dont know. I'm new at coding etc. They were the recommended tags so i pressed them.

Comment: i would say how come it is related to wordpress @MatiasCicero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the array, you simply need to loop over it.

```
//...
$data = json_decode($body, true);

foreach ($data['Time Series (1min)'] as $date => $row) {
    echo $date.' => '.$row['1. open'].'<br>';
}
```

Its a little tricky if you want just one value as its not the greatest structure, the date being the key. But you can use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function to fix that.

```
$min = array_values($data['Time Series (1min)']);

echo $min[0]['1. open']; //84.2000
```

Comment: Wow, it worked!! Can you also tell me how i can have only the first instance echoed instead of looping it for all occurrence?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about WordPress but thought your problem is related to reading the JSON keys that have spaces, you need to use brackets for this purpose see below a demo using `$.getJSON` reading the URL that you provided and printing the keys `1. open` from the response

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo').success(function(response) {
  var timeline = response['Time Series (1min)'];

  for (var i in timeline) {
    console.log(timeline[i]["1. open"]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```